# How to make string for file name?

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I try to create file in storage and for file name I use `webview.getTitle()` string.
When I save file with name for example "Google.jpg" or "Foreca.jpg" it works well, but...
not all webpage titles is so clear.

For example:

> "android - java.io.ioexception: open failed: einval (Invalid argument)
>   when saving a image to external storage - Stack Overflow:"

There is a lot of wrong characters, if I need this title put in file name.

Is there easy way to replace all this `:;?!/<>-` characters to `""`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `replaceAll()`:

```
String fileName = webview.getTitle();
filename = fileName.replaceAll("(\\p{Punct})","") // fixed \p
```

Check out the Java [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) for more.

Comment: Why you change `"(:;?!/<>-)",""` to `"(\p{Punct})",""` ?

Comment: @ArtursDerkintis http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html. \p{Punct} is shorthand for punctuation and symbols. All of these. "[!"#$%&'()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]".

Comment: There is one problem - in `"(\p{Punct})",""` it shows error `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )` why?

Comment: `\p{Punct}` is even better, don't you think so? - and I missed the separators: `(:|;|!|/|<|>|\?|\-)`. Both work fine, check at http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html; oh yes, in a Java String you have to escape the \ - so finally it's `"(\\p{Punct})"`